# Oracle track changes in database

Tags: oracle, snapshot

Good morning,

- We have an application which used to create daily reports.
- When a daily report is finished  it will be locked.
- But,sometimes daily report must be changed after locking.
- Therefore report will be unlocked.
- After the changes made the report will be locked again.

And what we would like to do:

- When report is unlocked we would like to take a snapshot
- When report is locked again we would like to take another snapshot of the records to compare with the previous snapsnot (at the moment of unlocking)  and see what changes were made in the records. **We would like to see the before and after values of each field.**

The daily report means around 40 tables and more hundred fields. So, when something has been changed in daily report it can happen in a few hundred fields of around 40 tables.

We are interested only to compare the status at the moment of unlock and at the moment of locking again. (With other words, we are not interested in all the changes made between unlock and locking again)

What is the best/recommended way to do this?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to go for FDA (Flashback Data Archive)

Kindly check the below links that explain how you can do that.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/flashback-and-logminer-enhancements-11gr1#flashback_data_archive

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1

Comment: THanks for your answer. I will read the descriptions and let you know if it is convenient for us or if we have any question.